# How to filter multiple array in object then display

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const data = {
      test1: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: ''},
      ],
      test2: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: 'theres an error in this field'},
        {error: 'theres an error here'},
      ],
      test3: [
        {error: ''},
        {error: 'theres an error'},
        {error: 'theres an error here'},
      ]
    };
```

how to filter data with an error value and display on it?

```
  const test1 = data.test1.filter(x => x.error !== ''); 
        const test2 = data.test2.filter(x => x.error !== ''); 
        const test3 = data.test3.filter(x => x.error !== ''); 
        
            <div>
               <div *ngFor="let test of test1">
                    {{test.error}}
               </div>
               <div *ngFor="let test of test2">
                    {{test.error}}
               </div>
               <div *ngFor="let test of test3">
                    {{test.error}}
               </div>
            </div>
```

I'm not sure it this is the correct way.

What I'm trying to do is display all the errors by listed without a space just like this

```
theres an error in this field
theres an error here
theres an error
theres an error here
```

Comment: Use "filter", not "some"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angular, and therefore Typescript, you should type your variables. `.some()` returns a boolean, not an array, so `const test1` should be `const test1:boolean`. And now you see you can't do `*ngFor="let test of test1"` on a boolean.

Replace `.some` with `.filter`, which does return an Array, and you should be good.

```
const test1: {error:string}[] = data.test1.filter(x => x.error !== '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all errors from data using:

```
interface ErrorResponse {
  error?: string;
}
const errors: ErrorResponse[] = Object.values(data).flat().filter(row => row.error);
```

and then display them using:

```html
<div *ngFor="let response of errors">
   {{response.error}}
</div>
```

Refs: [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).